# Repeatedly circling background animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I know that property animation is right solution for linear animation, but I was wondering how to make repeatedly circling background animation in Android?

For example, if following sequence of letters would present background:

ABCD

background picture would linearly move like this:
ABCD -> DABC -> CDAB -> BCDA -> ABCD and so on.

Does any1 have idea for this problem?